# How can I inherit all of the properties and controls along with the code from a previously created form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, inheritance

If I had to say it in a different way, what I want is to create a form that will work as the skeleton for my other forms.

I want one form that will work as the base for other 10 forms, to have the same starting functionality and appearance. The same controls, the code and properties of each one of the events of those controls, etc.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd usually just use a UserControl for reusability, but you can inherit one Form from another:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form1
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The constructor on the base Form (Form1) is called first, then the ctor on the child Form (Form2).

At runtime, you can see the controls from the base Form on the child Form, along with any other controls specific to just the child Form. Events, properties, etc. attached to controls that are defined on the base Form all carry over to the child Form.

[image]

The designer will even show the base Form's controls, although they're locked and cannot be moved or removed without editing the base Form directly (see the small icon on controls defined in the base Form):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create different forms, but populate each of them with a shared `UserControl`, which allows you to define the shared UI and functionality. Visual Studio has first-class support for creating user controls and using them in other forms. This does not allow you to define behaviour or appearance that is only defined for top-level forms, though.

It is equally possible to create a class that inherits from the form class generated by Visual Studio. It would inherit all controls, event handlers and properties. [See MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s82eeh07(v=vs.110).aspx)